# Log scheduling and archival policy in ROS

Tags: ros, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for log archival package  which should be able to help me in based on below policy.
(1) whenever log file (system.log) size >30859 or file is 3 day old then it should archive the same with new name system.log1 and again start the feeding the log in system.log file from start after truncating its content.
I am going to write all the debug statements in log file through  ROS c++ code in linux environment.
Any immediate help will be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255567/log-scheduling-and-archival-policy-in-ros/) by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2017-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On Linux, a flexible solution is [logrotate](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)

It allows logs to be archived based on age and/or size; archives logs may be compressed; versions may be capped: etc

When using log rotate on a running system which is not coded to handle its log files being closed/moved by an external process, use the `copytruncate` option as it will preserve the open file handle(s) being used by other programs.

---

Originally posted by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) with karma: 300 on 2017-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS doesn't provide any ROS-specific log-rotation facilities.

roscpp uses log4cxx as the logging framework, so you may be able to write a log4cxx configuration that specifies log rotation. (I don't know much about log4cxx but that seems like a feature it should have)

There are also a substantial number of linux tools that can do this, so perhaps one of those would be appropriate for your use case.

If you find an appropriate linux tool and want to use it from within a launch file, you may be able to write a wrapper script that you can use with the roslaunch `launch-prefix`.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-02-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1